# Allow customer to only read/view PDF files uploaded by admin

Tags: php, magento, pdf, file-upload

In our website admin is uploading `PDF` files from WYSIWYG editor and in user account we have a tab which shows that uploaded files.

The logged in customer can only read that `PDF` file but can not `download` or `print` it. The file is meant only for reading purpose. Also user should not be able to view the file location from address bar or file upload path.

I have tried implemented [PDF.JS](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) which is a a general-purpose, web standards-based platform for parsing and rendering PDFs, but it converts my PDF file to `image`.

User can view that PDF in image format but general feature like `searching text` is not working though.

Any other php pdf viewer that does the job is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [Disable save button in Adobe PDF reader and hide menu bar in IE window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880444/disable-save-button-in-adobe-pdf-reader-and-hide-menu-bar-in-ie-window) in the sense that you are asking something that is impossible in general. When you serve a PDF, you can not force the end user to use a specific plug-in. When you serve a PDF, an end user can always capture the PDF bytes.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for the info, but it would be great if you suggest how text search works in PDF.JS.

Comment: Huh? That is a completely different question. Text search will never work if you opt to use raster images; you need vector data (fonts, glyphs,...) if you want text search. Your question sounds like: "How can I watch TV on a radio?" The answer is: "Use a TV."