# How to create PDF non-editable without encrypting it using iText7

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to make pdf non-editable.
My pdf has attachment, I am able to delete the attachment from pdf when I open it in acrobat-reader.
I want to generate pdf with which make it non-editable where user cannot attach new attachment/delete existing attachment

I am using itext 7 for generating PDF

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable save button in Adobe PDF reader and hide menu bar in IE window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880444/disable-save-button-in-adobe-pdf-reader-and-hide-menu-bar-in-ie-window)

Comment: There is feature to render content to image on pdf. Have not tried it via code.

Comment: I do not think it's possible to disallow content modification without encrypting the document (it is, if you do). Maybe you should explore other venues, like rendering the PDF as an image?